# How to apply python scikit-learn to images/sound/videos for machine learning?

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, scikit-learn

It would be really helpful if someone can explain and give an example of how to apply machine learning algorithms using scikit-learn and python to images,sound or videos. I know how to apply it to csv file just want to learn how it can be extended for multimedia files.
Thankyou

Comment: you need good feature engineering ;)

Comment: To images, maybe - basically you'd need to go from images to theirs representations as a list of color values. Don't know about sound, but I am afraid, that processing videos in Python won't be efficient. I've used OpenCV in the past and switch to C++ and OpenCV instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [a section](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#image-feature-extraction) in the sklearn documentation on feature extracting that focuses on working with images. There's also [a section](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/#loading-from-external-datasets) of the docs that talk about working with images, video and audio. I suggest you spend some time going through these sections and the rest of the documentation.

The [MNIST dataset](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/#downloading-datasets-from-the-mldata-org-repository) is a standard dataset of images of hand written digits that is used in a lot of examples so if you're searching google for examples "MNIST sklearn" will probably be helpful.